# How to overwrite Event Handler defined in Angular > vendor.js?

Tags: angular, event-handling, vendor

I need to pass {passive: true} option to an existing event handler.
The handler is defined in the vendor.js file.

```
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', <handler1>);
    document.addEventListener('touchend', <handler2>);
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', <handler3>);
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', <handler4>);
```

I need to make this like:

```
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', <handler1>, {passive:true});
    document.addEventListener('touchend', <handler2>, {passive:true});
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', <handler3>, {passive:true});
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', <handler4>, {passive:true});
```

But I am not supposed to directly edit vendor.js
Then, how should I pass this {passive: true} option to the listener from a different file in my angular project.

---

I want to follow the process above to remove the 'touchmove' event listener, so that I can make scrolling smooth in my web application.

[let me know if any additional information is required]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself from online sources.

I can include CDN : 
node_modules/default-passive-events/dist/index.js

This can make all the event listeners passive by default.

Thus, bypassing the issue of passing { passive: true }